# jQuery runs the second time but not the first

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code to post a comment on my website

```
$('#leave-comment').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        post_comment();
    }
});
```

Then the following is the post_comment function

```
$('#leave-comment').submit();

$('#frm-leave-comment').unbind('submit');

$('#frm-leave-comment').submit(function(e) {

    // Code here for submit

}
```

When I press enter the first time it runs the keypress (verified by putting an alert in). It also gets the correct key pressed (enter - 13) and it also runs the post_comment function.

The problem is it doesn't submit the form

```
$('#frm-leave-comment').submit(function(e) {
```

However, the second time I press enter it does submit the form and works perfectly.

One thing to note is that the first block of code is run from a page loaded with ajax.

The second block of code is in an external javascript loaded when the page loads.

I have checked jquery isn't loaded twice.

There are other niggly things that are happening also like if I wrap the top block of code in a $(document).ready it doesn't fire the code and when using stopPropagation in other places on my website it works the second time but not the first so I think it's just a problem with the way jquery is loaded and not the above code.

Does anybody have an idea as to what may be happening here?

Comment: There is no need for ` \ ` in `$(\'#leave-comment\')`

Comment: When you use jQuery `.submit` with a `function`, it becomes a handler to occur when the submit event is triggered naturally on the page. It sounds like you want to trigger `submit` manually, so you'd need to lose the function and just call `submit();`. Read more: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Why do you have those slashes in your first code snippet?  Additionally, when you first call `$('#leave-comment').submit();`, wouldn't that cause the page to reload to the form's target action?  Thus nullifying everything that happens in JavaScript after that line?  It's not really clear to me what your `post_comment` function is intending to accomplish.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen The code is within php tags and forgot to remove them when posting on here. I will edit.

Comment: @David please see above comment for your first question. When I call submit I put in e.preventDefault to stop the form submitting. The issue isn't that the code above isn't working. The issue is that it only works the second time I press Enter.

Comment: @Jon Uleis Do I need to do what you suggest even though it is working? The problem is that it doesn't work the first time enter is pressed but on the second time it is pressed.

Comment: @DanielOrmerod Yes. David's answer below does a good job explaining how to clean up your code.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your form doesn't have any default "submit" action taking place?  At least this appears to be what you claim in your comment above:

> When I call submit I put in e.preventDefault to stop the form submitting.

So let's break down what your function is doing:

**First time you call the function:**

1. `$('#leave-comment').submit(); // does nothing, by your design`
2. `$('#frm-leave-comment').unbind('submit'); // removes any existing submit handler, so doesn't observably do anything`
3. `$('#frm-leave-comment').submit(function(e) { /*...*/ }); // adds a new submit handler, to be used *the next time* the form is submitted`

**Second time you call the function:**

1. `$('#leave-comment').submit(); // invokes your submit handler`
2. `$('#frm-leave-comment').unbind('submit'); // removes your submit handler`
3. `$('#frm-leave-comment').submit(function(e) { /*...*/ }); // re-adds *the same submit handler* you just removed`

So the first time you execute this function, you're not actually submitting anything.  You're just binding the submit handler to be used *the next time* you execute this function.

*And* you keep un-binding and re-binding the same submit handler.

This is vastly overcomplicating things.  Remove that `post_comment` function entirely and just bind your submit handler when the page loads:

```
$(function () {
    $('#frm-leave-comment').submit(function(e) {
        // Code here for submit
    }
});
```

Then in your `keypress` handler, simply submit the form:

```
$('#leave-comment').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        $('#leave-comment').submit();
        $('#frm-leave-comment').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for your well explained answer. I should have mentioned it in my original post but I took it out to avoid confusing it. The reason I run the post_comment function is because I pass an ID of which form is being submitted as the comments box is repeated on the page many times. So for example I call post_comment(243); and then in the function I do this - $('#frm-feed-leave-comment-'+id+'').submit(function(e) { - Doing it the way you suggest would mean I could only do it if I include the code as inline javascript but would rather keep it in the external js file.

Comment: Apologies run out of characters. Is there a way to do it with running the function?

Comment: @DanielOrmerod: You could still have a single submit handler for all of your forms, and just call `$('#frm-feed-leave-comment-'+id).submit()` in your `keypress` handler.  It's difficult to be specific since this information isn't in the question.  But the root of the problem isn't really related to that.  The root of the problem is that on your first keypress you *bind* the submit handler, but you don't invoke it.